# onListItemClick won't start

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to put onListItemClick, but when I start my app nothing happens with onListItemClick. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
    employeeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            search(employeeList);
        }
    });

}

public void search(View view) {
    // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
    cursor = db
            .rawQuery(
                    "SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title  FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?",
                    new String[] { "%" + searchText.getText().toString()
                            + "%" });
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.employee_list_item,
            cursor, new String[] { "firstName", "lastName", "title" },
            new int[] { R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title });
    employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);

}




    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmployeeDetails.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

}

There is no error messages and search is working normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

register an **OnItemClickListener()** with **setOnItemClickListener** for your listview like this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmployeeDetails.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(pos);
        intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);                
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but why there are errors when I put atOveride and without it isn't? And I get error at this line:                 Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(pos);               saying: The method getItem(int) is undefined for the type AdapterView<capture#1-of ?>

Answer (score 1):

```
employeeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

add these line below the above line

```
employeeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
employeeList .setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

**Updated::** sample code

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(mWebView);
    }
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: thank you, but are you sure for this line: employeeList .setOnItemClickListener(this);  ? Because it's showing error The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (EmployeeList). Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your listener as `listview.setOnItemClickListener(this)` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     // Your Code Goes Here
});
```